# What is the line described by $x + y = y + z = \frac{x+z}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to find the line in $R^3$ representated by $x + y = y + z = \frac{x+z}{2}$

I can see that $$x = z$$ $$y = 0$$

And I know that a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be represented by $$ax+by+c=0$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Careful: $ax+by+c=0$ determines a **line** in $\mathbb{R^2}$, it is a **plane** in $\mathbb{R^3}$. What exactly do you have to do? What is meant by *"finding the line"* with the given information?

Comment: Wouldnt that be the bisector line in the x-z plane, since y=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

There may be faster approaches based on intuition, but I find the following approach based on solving a linear system of equation to be quite systematic.

Firstly, write it in matrix-vector form:
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right) \quad .
\end{equation}

Secondly, derive the extended coefficient matrix from it. Make sure to add a third line, so there is one line for each variable:
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 &  0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &  0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right) \quad .
\end{equation}

Thirdly, solve the underdetermined system of equations by introducing a parameter $\lambda$:
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 &  0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &  1 & \lambda\\
\end{array}\right) \rightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 &  0 & \lambda\\
0 & 1 &  0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &  1 & \lambda\\
\end{array}\right) \quad .
\end{equation}

Et voilà, you have a parametric representation of your line:
\begin{equation}
\vec{x} = \lambda\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right) \quad .
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asked to find the line in $R^3$ representated by $x + y = y + z = \frac{x+z}{2}$
>   I can see that $$x = z$$ $$y = 0$$

This means the line lies in the $xz$-plane (because $y=0$) and in that plane, it is the (main) bisector (because $x=z$); so it is the unique line in the $xz$-plane that makes a $45^{\circ}$-angle with the positive $x$- and $z$-axis.

> And I know that a line in $R^3$ can be represented by $$ax+by+c=0$$

Careful (repeating my comment): $ax+by+c=0$ determines a **line** in $\mathbb{R^2}$, it is a **plane** in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

In such questions, it is impotrtant to proceed by successive equivalences.

Let us write the system under the slightly different form :

$$2x + 2y = 2y + 2z = x+z$$

which is evidently equivalent to:

$$\cases{2x+2y=2y+2z\\2y + 2z = x+z}$$

or

$$\cases{x=z\\2y + z = x} \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \cases{x=z\\y=0}$$

Why this equivalence ? because both implications $\Longrightarrow$ and $\Longleftarrow$ are almost evident.

Thus the answer is the intersection of bissector plane $z=x$ and vertical plane $y=0$.

A different equivalent description can be obtained by saying that the line can be described as the set of points $M_x(x,0,x)=x\vec{u}$ with $\vec{u}=(1,0,1)$.

Answer (score -1):

From x+y=y+z
It can be deduced that x=z
And from x+y = 0.5(x+z) while x= z
x + y = 0.5(x+x) = x

Thus y = 0

thus the equation can be concluded that
X=Z
Which is the equation of the line

Comment: I don't agree, you can't conclude that $z=2y$.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the question, I fixed it now sir